# A lot of errors in xfce after connecting to VNC

Tags: 16.04, xfce, remote-desktop, vnc

I've recently installed a TightVNC Server on a VPS using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) at DigitalOcean. However after doing everything step by step, and finally connecting to the remote desktop...I'm getting a lot of errors and the whole thing is very slow.

[image]

Any ideas how to repair that? Thanks.

Comment: How was the sever setup - was Xfce installed or did you install it manually, if so using what command?

Comment: @Wilf sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver this is the command.

Comment: Ok, it should have the needed bits if it installed properly... could you open a terminal/TTY/SSH session and find what process names are running that could cause this (you can either search through `top`, `htop`, `ps` etc, or if in a terminal on that desktop (try 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+T') use `xprop` or `xwininfo` to find out

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh.. Took me a lot of hours to figure it out...

~/.vnc/xstartup should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Not:

```
~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```